# Latest NodeJS version

Tags: node.js

Is there any public api that provides latest NodeJS version?

Currently I must use webscraping of https://nodejs.org/en/ to get this number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to check the version number of the latest release, you can download

https://nodejs.org/download/release/index.json

Entries are sorted most recent first, and you can check the `lts` flag to differentiate LTS releases from current ones.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). To download, compile, and install the latest release of node:

```
nvm install node
```